# JQuery keeping old values on variable assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm modifying a profile editor and have run into a problem with the delete functionality.

The profile search page shows 10 results at a time.  Each result row contains a Delete button. When the delete button is clicked a modal is shown that warns the user about the delete action and asks for confirmation.  On confirmation the modal is faded out and the deleted row is removed from the results.

After that, when the delete button in another row is clicked and confirmed, the username variable is not being assigned the new value.

```
$('#deleteButton').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).data().to_delete !== undefined) {
    var username = $(this).data().to_delete;
    var row = $(this).data().row_to_delete;
    $.ajax({
      url: getDjangoUrl('profile_delete', username),
      type: 'DELETE',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
          bootstrapAlert('success', 'Successfully deleted profile ' + username);
          table.fnDeleteRow(row);
        } else if (result.error) {
          bootstrapAlert('Error', 'Error deleting profile ' + username);
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        bootstrapAlert('Error', 'You do not have permission to delete ' + username);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The modal contains the $('#deleteButton') element.  When I inspect the element it has the correct value.
When I console.log(username) I'm seeing the previously deleted username every time.
Shouldn't

```
var username = $(this).data().to_delete;
```

be assigning the value from the button on click?  How is it even triggering the event if it's not getting tied to the new button? (I realize it's not a new button really, but the attributes I want have been assigned the proper value)

I looked at this solution but the addition of .off() didn't do me any good:
[Variable keeps old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803421/variable-keeps-old-value)

html of the modal:

```
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Are you are you want to delete this profile?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This will permanently delete this profile file!
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a id="deleteButton" href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-to_delete="abrown" data-row_to_delete="0">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The table is built as follows:

```
var toolbar = '<a class="edit btn">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-delete delete">Disable</a>';

var table = $('#profileTable').iidsBasicDataGrid({
  'bProcessing': true,
  'bServerSide': true,
  'bDeferRender': true,
  'sAjaxSource': getDjangoUrl('profile_order_list_json'),
  'aoColumns': [
    null,
    null,
    {
      'sWidth': '20%',
      'mData': null,
      'sClass': 'center',
      'sDefaultContent': toolbar,
      'bSearchable': false,
      'bSortable': false
    }
  ],
  'fnDrawCallback': function () {
    $('a.edit').each(function (button) {
      var username = $($(this).parents('tr')[0]).find('td').first().html();
      $(this).attr('href', getDjangoUrl('profile_edit', username));
    });
    $('a.delete').each(function (button) {
      var username = $($(this).parents('tr')[0]).find('td').first().html();
      $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
      $(this).attr('data-target', '#deleteModal');
      $(this).click(function () {
        var rowToDelete = table.fnGetPosition($(this).parent().parent().find('td')[0])[0];
        $('#deleteModal').find('#deleteButton').attr('data-to_delete', username);
        $('#deleteModal').find('#deleteButton').attr('data-row_to_delete', rowToDelete);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you also share the html?

Comment: Strang use of data, normally you use it like `$(this).data("to_delete");`

Comment: Where is the assigning happening?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `data()` like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how are you building your result table, or if it is a third, but in a way that can be solved is the following:

```
function buildResultSearchTable(dataCollection) {
    var rows = [];

    // Omitted for simplicity
    dataCollection.forEach(function (data, index) {
        var $rowTpl = $('Template for row');
        $rowTpl.data('to_delete', data);
        // Process for filling the columns
        rows.push($rowTpl); 
    }, this);

    // $table variable is defined in some place of code and contains a reference to <TABLE> tag
    $table.append(rows);
    $table.on('click', 'tr > td > input:button', function (event) {
        var username = $(this).parents('tr').data('to_delete');

        if (username) {
            // Any delete logic
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this solution help you a resolve you issue.

**UPDATE:**

This a brief [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7kNLB/)