# Images appending twice in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably just a dumb mistake I'm making but I'm having a problem with this event handler

```
$('.instagram').on('didLoadInstagram', function(event, response)
```

running twice so my images get appended twice.  I know its running twice because I checked it with a print statement.  Here is the full function in my code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#pictures").html("");
      $('.instagram').on('willLoadInstagram', function(event, options) {
        console.log(options);
      });
      $('.instagram').on('didLoadInstagram', function(event, response) {
        console.log(response)
        console.log("go")
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var DOM_img = document.createElement("img");
            var link = document.createElement('a'); 
            DOM_img.setAttribute('src', response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url);
            link.setAttribute('href', response.data[i].link);
            link.appendChild(DOM_img)
            pictures.appendChild(link);
        }

      });
      $('.instagram').instagram({
        search: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        distance: document.getElementById('Distance').value
      },
        count : 33,
        clientId: 'removed'
      });
    });
});
```

Whats happening is that when you click the button the it will print out an extra div 'pictures' for each time youve clicked the button.  So, the first will give one set, the second will give the set then give its duplicate, and the third will give the set then two duplicates.

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803421/variable-keeps-old-value

Comment: Why are you attaching the instagram events inside the button click? Every time you click you're attaching new event handlers.

Comment: you'll want to clear the old values using "off"

Comment: Where are you setting `pictures` for this append: `pictures.appendChild(link);` - by default won't jQuery treat that as an ID selector? so by saying pictures.append it may be referencing an ongoing object, even though you're specifying to html(""). Maybe you should change that to an actual selector and use .empty to clear the div

Comment: Im very new to jquery so that probably answers your question.  I wanted to make it so that the search runs when you click the button because the variables lat and lng dont appear until the page loads and is interacted with.  Im guessing I should take some of the code outside the button event?

Comment: Also, Kai, I dont know if I fully understand your response but Ill try to reply.  Pictures is a div that I am storing them in which can be displayed to the html page.  I unfortunately dont know what an ID selector and an actual selector are.  Lastly, I tried using .empty instead of .html("") but that did not work

Answer (score 1):

As Stryner correctly noticed you're attaching multiple event handlers on the `$('.instagram')` object. You should move only the `instagram` function call inside the button click event handler and left everything else outside.

Example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#pictures").html("");
  $('.instagram').on('willLoadInstagram', function(event, options) {
    console.log(options);
  });
  $('.instagram').on('didLoadInstagram', function(event, response) {
    console.log(response)
    console.log("go")
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      var DOM_img = document.createElement("img");
      var link = document.createElement('a'); 
      DOM_img.setAttribute('src', response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url);
      link.setAttribute('href', response.data[i].link);
      link.appendChild(DOM_img)
      pictures.appendChild(link);
    }
  });
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.instagram').instagram({
      search: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        distance: document.getElementById('Distance').value
      },
      count : 33,
      clientId: 'removed'
    });
  });
});
```